# ShellExecuteEx .html not registered SE_ERR_NOASSOC (when running from Delphi-Debugger)

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-10, windows-shell, delphi-10.3-rio

In the moment, I got a problem trying to open an URL (like http://example.com/test/customer.html?sessionid=291697) with ShellExecuteEx. 
My goal is to see it in the
registered standard browser (e.g. Firefox, IE, Chrome...)

```pascal
procedure RunNoWait(AProgram: string; AParameters: string; AWorkingDirectory: string; AUAC: Boolean; AShow: Integer = SW_SHOWNORMAL);
var
  sei: TShellExecuteInfoW;
  aRes: Boolean;
begin
  // Does not work too:
  //  aRes := ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', PWideChar(AProgram), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
  //  if aRes <= 32 then begin
  //    RaiseLastOSError;
  //  end;

  FillChar(sei, SizeOf(sei), 0);
  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
  sei.Wnd := Application.Handle;
  sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  if AUAC then begin
    sei.lpVerb := PWideChar('runas'); 
  end
  else begin
    sei.lpVerb := PWideChar('open');
  end;
  sei.lpFile := PWideChar(WideString(aProgram));
  sei.lpDirectory := PWideChar(WideString(AWorkingDirectory));
  sei.lpParameters := PWideChar(WideString(AParameters));
  sei.nShow := AShow;

  aRes := ShellExecuteExW(@sei);
  try
    if not aRes then begin
      RaiseLastOSError;
    end;

  finally
    CloseHandle(sei.hProcess);
  end;
end;

// later, I call this with:
  AAddress := 'http://example.com/test/customer.html?sessionid=291697';
  RunNoWait(AAddress, '', '', False);
```

The WinApi returns **GetLastError 1155 (ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION)** and 
FormatError returns '**There is no application associated with the specified file name extension.**'.

When I copy the URL into Windows Explorer, the website is opened in Firefox, for example...

Any ideas, why the URL cannot be opened programmatically?

[edit:]
Just found out, that it works with standard browser set to Microsoft Edge... 
But still doesn't work with Firefox, IE and Chrome.
And I can easily open the URL with those browsers manually...

[edit:]
One more hint: while testing with standard-browser IE, I noticed, that it works, when IE is already open(???)

[edit:]
**The Problem only exists when starting the app from Delphi-Debugger.
Does anybody know why?**

Comment: ".. copy the URL into Windows Explorer .." - What does that mean?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is probably `http://example.com/test/customer.html?sessionid=291697` is not recognized (extension=html?sessionid=291697). Create a file with that name, double click, and you'll get the same.

Comment: 'copy the URL into Windows Explorer' just a test with Windows Explorer, to show, that there *is* a registered browser on this system... manual copy-paste with keyboard ;-)

Comment: Just found out, that it works with standard browser set to Microsoft Edge... 
But still doesn't work with Firefox, IE and Chrome...

Comment: And I can easily open the URL with those browsers manually...

Comment: Do you exit your program immediately after calling that function? If so, try to add `SEE_MASK_NOASYNC` to `sei.fMask`. Also make sure to call `CoInitialize()` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Don't exit the program and added CoInitialize(nil) at start - still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to URL-encode the parameters (or even the full URL): `AAddress := 'http://example.com/test/customer.html' + URLEncode('?sessionid=291697')`. See http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=191530 for `URLEncode` function.

Comment: Check if "http" is associated with the programs that don't work in control panel, default programs.

Comment: @zett42 `CoInitialize(nil)` has nothing to do with this, and if this is a UI app, it's already been called.

Comment: Try using `sei.lpVerb := nil;` instead of `sei.lpVerb := 'open';`  Not all apps use `'open'` as their default verb.

Comment: @JerryDodge ShellExecute can require COM. (at)RemyLebeau True but I believe all protocols use "open" and anything else has compatibility issues.

Comment: @zett42 there is no need to url-encode in this case, as there are no reserved characters in the url that need to be encoded. However, if you are going to url-encode in general, DON'T encode the `?` that separates the path from the query, the `&` that separates name/value pairs, or the `=` that separates names from values in each pair, eg: `AAddress := 'http://example.com/test/customer.html?' + URLEncode('sessionid') + '=' + URLEncode('291697')`

Comment: Why are you using SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS when you just close the handle? You can't rely on getting a process handle for protocols since DDE is common for browsers.

Comment: @Anders: No, not all protocols use `open`. Adobe Acrobat DC, for example, uses `Open with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC`, and using `open` as the verb will fail. Using `nil` indicates that the default action (the one triggered by a double-click) will be used.

Comment: @KenWhite I know how it's supposed to work but IIRC mIRC and some other software would manually read %proto%\shell\open\command from the registry. The user can't see nor choose the verb so there is no reason to pick anything else. And are you sure Adobe uses that name as the verb? MSDN hints that spaces are not valid in verbs (the key name, not the display name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I see, that I was looking into the wrong direction:

The problem existed only, when starting the app from Delphi Debugger.

All browsers work, if you start the app without Delphi.

[edit:]
Just found out why: Tools->Options->Debugger-Options->Embarcadero-Debugger->'debug in spawned processes' was active.
Seems like those browsers do not want to get debugged... (anyway, we have no source for them)

Answer (score 0):

According to `TShellExecuteInfoW`, the charset you use unicode, so `ShellExecute` and `ShellExecuteEx` both refer to the version `***W`.
The type of `sei.lpVerb` is assgined incorrect.
 See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2007453/10611792)

> As long as there are no non-ANSI characters in your string literal,
>   the compiler won't have any trouble generating the string as ANSI
>   instead of Unicode in this situation.

You should:

```
const
  method = 'open';
sei.lpVerb := PWideChar(method);
```

The same issue that can reproduce in C++:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = { 0 };
    sei.cbSize = sizeof(sei);
    sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI| SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT| SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    sei.lpVerb = (LPCWSTR)"open";
    sei.lpFile = L"http://example.com/test/customer.html?sessionid=291697";
    sei.hwnd = NULL;

    BOOL bInitialized = SUCCEEDED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE));

    if (ShellExecuteExW(&sei))
    {
        //Success
        printf("Success \n");
    }
    else
    {
        //Failed
        printf("Failed %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    if (bInitialized)
    {
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The fix is to modify `(LPCWSTR)"open"` to `L"open"`.

Comment: Just tried const methodOpen = 'open'; sei.lpVerb := PWideChar(methodOpen); No difference...